# Drive variable is not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script to list big files on list of servers. Unfortunately it is not listing anything. However, if I replace the $_.Name by the string D:\ it works fine.

```
$servers = Get-Content "servers1.txt" | Select-String -pattern `
    "^[^#]"
foreach ($line in $servers) {
    $svr = echo $line | %{$_.Line.split(':')[2]}
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $svr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object __SERVER,Name |
    foreach {
        Invoke-command {Get-ChildItem -path $_.Name -rec | Where-Object `
        -FilterScript {($_.Length -ge 3GB) -and ($_.Name -notlike "*.mdf")}} -computername $svr
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is scoping issue: in remote command $_.Name does not exist. Try this instead:

```
Invoke-command {
    param ($Path)
    Get-ChildItem -path $Path -rec | Where-Object {($_.Length -ge 3GB) -and ($_.Name -notlike "*.mdf")}
} -ComputerName $svr -ArgumentList $_.Name
```